# 'handleMenuClick' is not defined

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have the following react component, but I am not sure what I am missing here, because the function is indeed defined, the error must be something so simple but cant find what

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col, Tabs, Menu, Dropdown, Button, Icon, message } from 'antd';
import PageHeader from '../../components/utility/pageHeader';
import Box from '../../components/utility/box';
import LayoutWrapper from '../../components/utility/layoutWrapper';
import ContentHolder from '../../components/utility/contentHolder';
import basicStyle from '../../settings/basicStyle';
import IntlMessages from '../../components/utility/intlMessages';




export default class extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
        this.handleMenuClick = this.handleMenuClick.bind(this);        
    }

    handleButtonClick(e) {
        message.info('Click on left button.');
        console.log('click left button', e);
    }

    handleMenuClick(e) {
        message.info('Click on menu item.');
        console.log('click', e);
    }

    render(){
        const { rowStyle, colStyle, gutter } = basicStyle;
        const TabPane = Tabs.TabPane;
        const  menu = (
            <Menu onClick={handleMenuClick}>
            <Menu.Item key="1"><Icon type="user" />menu item</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2"><Icon type="user" />2nd menu item</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="3"><Icon type="user" />3rd item</Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
        );

        return (
        <div>
            <LayoutWrapper>
            <PageHeader>{<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.PageAdministration" />}</PageHeader>
            <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
            <Col md={12} sm={12} xs={24} style={colStyle}>
                <Box
                title={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.siteCollectionsTitle" />}
                subtitle={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.siteCollectionsTitle" />}
                >
                <ContentHolder>
                    <Dropdown.Button onClick={handleButtonClick} overlay={menu}>
                    Dropdown
                    </Dropdown.Button>
                </ContentHolder>
                </Box>
            </Col>
            </Row>
        </LayoutWrapper>
        </div>
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `onClick={this.handleMenuClick}`.